# Is it possible to validate a response which comes in a different API call using Karate

Tags: api, karate

I am working on an application where I have 2 modules, Lets say module 1 and module 2.

Steps:

- I send an API request from module 1 using the API: customer/getAccountBalance
- Receives 200 OK response in return from module 2.
- Later in time (like few seconds) Module 2 initiates another call and sends another response to module 1
- Module 2 will use API: customer/balanceResponse.

How can I validate the below points using Karate:

- I receive 200 OK for my first request in step 1 above
- I receive a response in API: customer/balanceResponse